# Python's sys.settrace won't create c_call events

Tags: python, debugging

The documentation for `sys.settrace` says that it can report calls to c or builtin functions. When I try following program, I expect to see a `c_call` event, but nothing happens:

```
import sys

def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    print(frame, event, arg)
    return tracer

sys.settrace(tracer)

x = len([1,2,3])
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Can anyone post an example use of `sys.settrace` which generates a `c_call` event?

EDIT: Initially I tried it with Python 3.2, and it gave me no events. Now I tried it with Python 2.7 and it gave me two `call`-s (not `c_call`-s). Still weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs are wrong, `c_call` events will never be sent to your trace function: http://bugs.python.org/issue17799